# Do we know anything in detail about the effect of the black death on Sub-Saharan Africa?

Tags: middle-ages, africa, disease, black-death

When I was in school 20-odd years ago, historians were still unsure about whether or not the black death traveled through Sub-Saharan Africa to any large degree, in large part because the vector (merchant ships) didn't visit many Sub-Saharan African ports and historical records of the area during the Middle Ages were few and far between.

Now that we have a few more histories of individual Sub-Saharan African fiefdoms through the Middle Ages, has anything more been unearthed on whether the bubonic plague affected Sub-Saharan Africa to any significant degree?

Comment: Can't write an answer right now, but two recent papers on the subject may be of interest. [The Black Death may have transformed medieval societies in sub-Saharan Africa](https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2019/03/black-death-may-have-transformed-medieval-societies-sub-saharan-africa)  and [Putting Africa on the Black Death map: Narratives from genetics and history](https://journals.openedition.org/afriques/2125)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gérard Chouin (professor of history and director of medieval and renaissance studies) is adamant that the medieval-era bubonic plague epidemic, the Black Death, spread to Sub-Saharan Africa and killed scores of people there as it did in Europe and the Mediterranean basin in the 14th century. More details in this link:https://docsbay.net/the-second-plague-pandemic-reach-subsaharan-africa